# Get sum of max per user

Tags: google-bigquery

If I wanted to craft a bigquery query for a table like:

```
user | value
------------
  1. |   1
  1. |   3
  2. |   1
  2. |   5
```

and i wanted to get 3 + 5, because these are the max per user, how would I do this in a single aggregate query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT SUM(value) value FROM (
  SELECT MAX(value) value
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  GROUP BY user
)
```

Comment: @rob - did  you have chance to check above solution?